# How are class types passed to JSNI code in GWT?

Tags: gwt, jsni

I am wrapping a JS library and one method takes a class/prototype as a parameter. ie:

```
installPlugin(Prototype)
```

How would the wrapped JSNI function for this method look?

```
public final void native installPlugin(Class<?> clazz) /*-{
    this.installPlugin(clazz);
}-*/;
```

This isn't correct but along the lines of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. In GWT, objects know their class (returned by `getClass()`) but `Class` instances don't have a reference to the constructors / prototype that would allow creating instances of that class.

If you can pass an instance of the class instead, you should be able to just use `obj.prototype`. It wouldn't work in DevMode though, where Java objects are *opaque handles* when passed to JSNI.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasBroyer, that's a sound explanation. Thanks for the warning regarding the opaque handles. I'm curious as to how DevMode will respond. I may stick to my hard coded native method `installPluginSoundJS() /*-{ installPlugin(SoundJS); }-*/;` and implement the method the way you suggested using the `obj.prototype`  heeding the DevMode warning. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your prototype should have .toJs() method which converts it into JavaScriptObject type. pass it instead of Java Prototype.

Comment: That's not how JSNI works. Only JS can create a JSO. JSO's can only be created natively in JS and the GWT framework/compiler allows them to be referenced from Java.

Comment: If he writes a wrapper he would probably have JSNI constructor of Prototype inside Java constructor, yes? So what's the trouble with storing JavaScriptObject as a private field of Java wrapper and access it anytime with .toJs() or .getJs(), whatever, method?